# What is the connection between motherhood and apple pie?

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms, expressions, american-english

I know the idiom *motherhood and apple pie* is used to denote some principles with which few disagree. But what is the connection between *motherhood* and *apple pie*? I am not very familiar with American culture. I want to understand what makes this phrase to mean what it means.

Comment: Please put spaces between your sentences, and please do not use backticks on ELU.  Monospace is nearly never appropriate here; you usually want italic.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the suggestion of not using backticks but why monospace is not appropriate here?

Comment: [1. American soldiers stationed overseas were quoted saying “mom and apple pie” when asked what they missed most being away from home, conjuring up cozy memories 2. A “motherhood and apple pie” issue is an issue which is universally agreed upon just as no one would disparage “motherhood” and everyone likes apple pie.](http://makingheadsortailsofidioms.com/2012/02/21/motherhood-and-apple-pie/)

Comment: @Geek Because one customarily uses italics to distinguish words and phrases that are mentioned rather than used. See [this question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/363). Monospace in particular looks incredibly ugly in properly typeset test, especially here where it is queerly colored to boot, and serves virtually no possible purpose on ELU outside the super-rare situation of formatting multiline snippets of computer code that requires precise vertical alignment; tables may fall into this category for want of a better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any connection, other than their being two things which no one could possibly object to.

(Not really relevant, but *apple pie* is also used in the expression 'as American as apple pie'.